# How do I create a longtable with custom section headers and table body?

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to create a macro with 3 columns with Chinese in the first column, Pinyin for the second, and English for the 3rd. Rows are broken up into different sections to represent different chapters in the book. It is supposed to look like this.[image: Designing Macro to look like this]

I got tired of writing it out and want to make my LaTeX document cleaner so I can see it better. Here is my macro:

```
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\longtable[p{.02\textwidth}p{.40\textwidth} p{.40\textwidth} p{.4\textwidth}]{4}{*}{
& Chinese Characters & Pinyin & English Translation \\ \hline
\section*{Lesson {#1}: {#2}} \\
\newcommand\row{\rownumber& {#3} & {#4} & {#5} \\}}
```

It is getting really cumbersome writing 300 lines with the same format.

```
\rownumber & 昨天比今天暖和。& Zuótiān bǐ jīntiān nuǎnhuo. & Yesterday was warmer than today. \\
```

If the macro doesn't work, maybe I can input some table data from a file? So I separate formatting and text. There is some text I want to keep in my main .tex file and maybe load most of the content from a file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do these section titles in the table depict the beginning of a section or is this table merely a summery and the section titles only refer to sections somewhere else in the document? If these section titles really depict the beginning of new sections, I would not recommend placing them inside a table. Rather, I would start a new table (with always the same column definitions and widhts) after every new section. If these section titles are only referring to sections, on the other hand, I would not use the `\section` macro for this but rather a `\multicolumn` and bold font.

Comment: It is surely possible to import data into LaTeX and have it formatted to fit a `tabular`-like environment. It depends on how the data source looks like. However, something seems to be missing from the code you provide, since `#1` and `#2` are not part of a `\newcommand` as it seems. Also, you probably don't want to print a new section title for every table row, so I wonder why you place everything into one macro.

Comment: I am using a table because I want to count all the total rows but separate them into sections without restarting the count. I use a longtable to separate the Chinese column, Pinyin, and then English. It is getting overwhelming because I want to separate the rows with definitions vs rows with sentences that are created from those definitions. Hopefully this makes sense. I guess I can make separate documents, one for sentences and the other for definitions strictly.

Comment: But you can still use separate `longtable` environments. The counter doesn't mind and will just continue after the next section anyways. Maybe you can add an example with such a defintion? I am still not quite sure how exactly you imagine to simplify things.

Comment: Maybe keep it simple: I would use one `longtable` for each section. You can define a `\newenvironment` to this end, so you will have the same column defintions for every instance. Then you could define one macro to add a row for a definition and another one for adding a row for an example sentence. Maybe this will make things easier already? Maybe, however, a tabular environment is not the right thing to start with ... (and the counter can be used outside of a table as well ...)

Comment: I am getting tired of typing     \rownumber & & &  \\
I will try to create a \newenvironment. What do you recommend to have 3 columns with same length between the columns and can be separated by section headers?

Comment: You will have to enter some kind of cell delimiter in any format. In CSV you will have to type comma or tabs ... I fear there is no way to simplify this ...

Comment: Ok thanks, I might try to add coloring to differentiate between certain rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like this (although I am not quite sure whether defining a macro for a single row really simplifies things ...). In any case, I would not place `\section`s inside a `tabular`-like environment. Actually, I think that the structure of the document even benefits from splitting up the tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\newenvironment{mytable}
    {\begin{longtable}
        {@{} p{.1\textwidth-6\tabcolsep} p{.3\textwidth} p{.3\textwidth} p{.3\textwidth} @{}}
    }
    {\end{longtable}}

\newcommand{\sentencerow}[3]{
    \rownumber & #1 & #2 & #3 \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}
 & \textbf{Chinese Characters} & \textbf{Pinyin} & \textbf{English Translation} \\ \hline
\end{mytable}

\section*{Lesson 1: Weather}

\begin{mytable}
\sentencerow{昨天比今天暖和。}{Zuótiān bǐ jīntiān nuǎnhuo.}{Yesterday was warmer than today.}
\sentencerow{名天比昨天冷。}{Míngtiān bǐ zuótiān lěng.}{Tomorrow will be colder than yesterday.}
\end{mytable}

\section*{Lesson 2: Transportation}

\begin{mytable}
\sentencerow{我想坐火车去北京。}{Wǒ xiǎng zuò huǒchē qù Běijīng.}{I want to go to Beijing by train.}
\end{mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks! This looks like it will simplify my document.

Comment: @Nick You can take a look at the `csvsimple` package or similar packages if you want to read data into your tables. The concrete settings depend on how your data looks like, of course

Comment: Ok, thanks. Ill consider the csvsimple package